# How do I compile the actual linux-modules-iwlwifi instead of the mainline kernel code from source

Tags: kernel, iwlwifi, source-packages

I'm doing some regulatory compliance work and I need the iwlxvt module and to modify the source of iwlwifi. The kernel modules installed by linux-modules-iwlwifi include the iwlxvt module that is part of the iwlwifi backports.

I've got my patch ready to go but if I follow the usual build instructions I get a kernel that doesn't even pass the modules check because it's missing things like zfs. Notably the source tree is *entirely missing iwlxvt* when installed from any Canonical source I've tried.  It looks like the sources installed from apt are insufficient to build the kernel installed from apt.

So obviously this isn't the real source. Is there a mechanism to get the source with all the open-but-not-GPL parts included?  Alternatively, how do I determine which iwl backports 'Core' version this is so I can download the real source and compile it manually.

Comment: Have you tried working with the iwlwifi backports? They can be found from both the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` package through apt and also from https://gitlab.com/vicamo/backport-iwlwifi-dkms.

Comment: Pretty sure this should be compiled as a standalone module but I could be wrong. Nearly all wireless drivers I've ever worked with are compiled and added into use independently from the kernel.

Comment: A search on [the gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/vicamo/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/-/find_file/debian/master?ref_type=heads) for iwlxvt shows the following path `drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/`

Comment: And the one from apt (the `backport-wilwifi-dkms` package), at least on 20.04, shows the following directory `/usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8324/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/` which I assume is for (to build) iwlxvt.

Comment: @mchid in 23.10 the iwlwifi backports appears to be built under the name linux-modules-iwlwifi, which is exactly what you get if you compile iwl wifi drivers from the mainline kernel. I don't think backport-iwlwifi-dmks exists anymore (and it doesn't require dkms).  Since the apt system for getting sources only pulls down the mainline kernel when I try to get the sources I don't know how to find out which release (Core) of the iwlwifi backports this is.

Comment: I got [this result](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=mantic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=iwlwifi&searchon=all) (from the universe repository) and downloading the source shouldn't be necessary as you should be able to build the module from this package and install the module using dkms. Although, `sudo apt build-dep backport-iwlwifi-dkms` will probably still help. You can see the [file list here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/all/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/filelist).

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the same version present in the system and then modify its source code.